# usb hid troubleshooting linux

Tags: linux, usb, usb-hid

I'm trying to get a java program to connect to a hid device on 
Fedora 30, but I get a 'errno 13' error when trying to connect

The software library creator and a user over on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469032/troubleshooting-purejavahidapi-library-opendevice-function) have confirmed it's not a software library problem

My user has already been added to the wheel, dialout, and input groups with
the same result

Can anyone suggest a way to get around this?

device path: /dev/input/by-id

0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Jun 13 09:02 usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315-event-kbd -> ../event5

Comment: Are you running your program as root? `Errno 13` is a permission denied error, so the problem seems really trivial.

Comment: no, it's being launched from inside netbeans. If my user is in the right group shouldn't I be able to access the device anyway?

Comment: Please edit question with uid and gid of the process that's trying to connect, the path of the device it's trying to connect, and the permissions of that device. You can use `strace` for additional information, if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the uid and gid of the process, it's launching from in my IDE Netbeans, it's not running long enough for me to run any additional commands